# How to connect html with sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have some database queries whom's data needs to be displayed over the html in the form of tables and graphs

```
<script>
    var objConnection = new ActiveXObject("adodb.connection");
    var strConn = "driver={sql server};server=ip;database=databasename;uid=username;password=password”;
    objConnection.Open(strConn);
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    var strQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.nodes";
    rs.Open(strQuery, objConnection);
    rs.MoveFirst();
    while (!rs.EOF) {
                document.write(rs.fields(0) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(1) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(2) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(3) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(4) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(5) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(6) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(7) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(8) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(9) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(10) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                document.write(rs.fields(11) + "<br/>");
     rs.movenext();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello there and welcome to stack overflow! Usually, you'll receive better answers if you in a clear manner elaborate on the context of your question as well as what you've tried, where you got stuck and what you're looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate html report in the database side and simply display the generated html in the web application.

You can use [FOR XML Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to generate HTML report.

There are many samples provided in the [Generating HTML reports using SQL Queries article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/generating-html-sql-server-queries/)

Also refer to below stackoverflow answers.

-[how do I convert a select statement result into an HTML table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711185/how-do-i-convert-a-select-statement-result-into-an-html-table-in-sql-server)
- [Convert a SQL query result table to an HTML table for email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070053/convert-a-sql-query-result-table-to-an-html-table-for-email)